# What is the purpose of extra <div> wrappers?

Tags: html, css

I occasionally see the following construct:

```
<div id="main-header-wrapper">
    <div id="main-header">
        <span>foo</span>
        <span>bar</span>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

There is nothing at all between `main-header-wrapper` and `main-header`. Why would one want to use the outer wrapper when there is already one level (i.e. `main-header`)?

Comment: It can be using in your js

Comment: if this is part of a template, most of the time they do this to allow theme designers to change the design without having to change the html, for example, how CSSZenGarden works: http://www.csszengarden.com/

Comment: This also future proofs the design if you want to add elements at different levels in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple aspects that could make a difference:

- Some layouts require this combination. If it is needed in your case depends on the css-rules applied. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234259/is-it-useful-to-container-wrapper-in-every-css-layout) for some details.
- JavaScript code may read/manipulate the DOM identifing the nodes by their id